# How to create a contourf plot from a table?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

As far as I understand the way to 3-d plot/ surface plot is "meshgrid".
But the data I have has a specific format:

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 10 |
| 1 | 0.2 | 12 |
| 1 | 0.3 | 13 |
| 2 | 0.1 | 11 |
| 2 | 0.2 | 12 |
| 2 | 0.3 | 14 |
| 3 | 0.1 | 11 |
| 3 | 0.2 | 12 |
| 3 | 0.3 | 15 |

The first and second column (X and Y) repeat themselves in that fashion, and I need to plot Z(X,Y).

How Do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
X = 1:1:3 % grid can be set by beginning:step:end
Y = 0.1:0.1:0.3
[x,y] = meshgrid(X,Y); % then make 2d domain 


% z values have to be done manually or can automate if you read your data from txt file
z = [10 12 13; 11 12 14; 11 12 15]; 

% and finally
surf(x,y,z)
```